# How to add theme switcher in next.js using antdesign?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, themes, antd

I want to add a theme switcher button to my dashboard layout. Basically, I am using two variants of my dashboard. One is the light theme and the other is a dark theme. I am using antdesign for UI with less support using [next-with-less](https://github.com/elado/next-with-less) plugin. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my global.less file content

```
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";
@primary-color: #26695c; // primary color for all components
@link-color: #1890ff; // link color
@success-color: #52c41a; // success state color
@warning-color: #faad14; // warning state color
@error-color: #f5222d; // error state color
@font-size-base: 14px; // major text font size
@heading-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); // heading text color
@text-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65); // major text color
@text-color-secondary: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45); // secondary text color
@disabled-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); // disable state color
@border-radius-base: 10px; // major border radius
@border-color-base: #d9d9d9; // major border color
@box-shadow-base: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); // major shadow for layers
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;700&display=swap");
html,
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

// @menu-highlight-color: white;
// @menu-item-active-bg: @primary-color;

:root {
  --primary-color: @primary-color;
  --light-primary-color: #e5edef;
  --success-color: @success-color;
  --background-light: #f3f5fa;

  --shadow-base: @box-shadow-base;
}

#__next {
  height: 100%;
}

.ant-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.ant-btn span {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.ant-card .ant-card-cover {
  width: 100%;
}
// .ant-menu:not(.ant-menu-horizontal) .ant-menu-item-selected {
//   background: @primary-color;
// }
```

and my next.config.js content

```
const withLess = require("next-with-less");

module.exports = withLess({
  reactStrictMode: false,
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and what issues are you facing?

Comment: @juliomalves i had created two files 1 is `global.less` which is above and other is `global.dark.less` with different environment variable values. But when i try to import both these files in my dashboard layout like `import light from 'global.less'` Next throw an error saying you can't import global in layout files.